# How to get the last element from array while comparing current element with next element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration, arrow-functions

I have an array which contains key-value pairs. Keys are (ID,Lat,Lon).

What I am trying to do is compare current element ID with next element ID and if they are equal put the Lat and Lon of current element in a object (in my case "point") and call a function (InjectIntoArray on that point which initializes a global array points[]).

When condition becomes false (i.e current id not equals next id), in else part I am putting the current elements Lat and Lon in a object and calling a function on that one, this is because the ID of next element is going to be different and I have to get all the Lat and Lon of current element ID.

The problem occurs when the the last element is being checked, it exits without obtaining the last record.(i.e list[lastElement]).

How can i get the Lat and Lon of all elements? Is there any better way to achieve this?

Here is my array -

```
var list = [
            { id: 100, Lat: 19.25, Lon: 74}, { id: 100, Lat: 19.79, Lon: 74.19 }, 
            { id: 101, Lat: 19.99, Lon:75.10 }, { id: 101, Lat: 20.37, Lon:68.9}, 
            { id: 119, Lat: 17, Lon: 70 }, { id: 107, Lat: -16, Lon: -165 }, 
            { id: 107, Lat: -15, Lon: -150 }
           ];
```

And the code-

```
 for (let i = 0; i < list.length - 1;i++) {
                        if (list[i].id == list[i+1].id) {
                            var point = { LATITUDE: list[i].Lat, LONGITUDE: list[i].Lon };
                            InjectIntoArray(point);
                        }
                        else {
                            var point = { LATITUDE: list[i].Lat, LONGITUDE: list[i].Lon };
                            InjectIntoArray(point);
                            plotRoute(false,2);
                            points = [];
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: frame the question properly.

Comment: And which position should be taken?

Comment: Please go read [ask], and show us what you have tried so far, and be specific about what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = [     { id: 100, Lat: 19.25, Lon: 74}, { id: 100, Lat: 19.79, Lon: 74.19 }, 
            { id: 101, Lat: 19.99, Lon:75.10 }, { id: 101, Lat: 20.37, Lon:68.9}, 
            { id: 119, Lat: 17, Lon: 70 }, { id: 107, Lat: -16, Lon: -165 }, 
            { id: 107, Lat: -15, Lon: -150 }
      ];
pivot = obj.reduce((acc,item) => {
    let {id,Lat,Lon} = item;
    if(!acc[id]) acc[id]= [];
    acc[item.id].push({Lat, Lon});
    return acc;
},{});

Object.keys(pivot).forEach((id) => {
    pivot[id].forEach(coords => {
        fn(coords.Lat,coords.Lon,id) //call your function here;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but your forEach on pivot was not working since the `Object.keys(pivot)`  was shown as undefined. However I have rephrased my question please take a look.